# Pass two (piped) shell commands as a parameter to a shell function

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have defined the following shell functions:

```sh
success() {
  printf "[\033[32mSUCCESS\033[0m]\n"
}

failure() {
  printf "[\033[31mFAILURE\033[0m]\n"
}

try() {
  result=$($* 2>&1)
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    failure
    echo $result
    exit 1
  fi
  success
}
```

This allows me to silently execute any command, capturing all the output, and display a `SUCCESS` or `FAILURE` message. Only if the command fails, the command output is displayed for debugging:

```sh
try rm -r $tmp
```

But I just realized that it's limited to a single command, and fails miserably for a command piped to another with `|`:

```sh
try git archive --format=tar HEAD | tar xf - -C $tmp
```

Because `try` is executed only on the `git` command, and then the output of `try` is piped to `tar`, instead of the output of `git`.

**Is it possible to pass the two commands `git ... | tar ...` as a single parameter to `try`**, capturing the output of both, and check if both `git` and `tar` returned `0`?

Any other consideration maybe, to achieve my goal?

Comment: what happens if you do `try git archive --format=tar HEAD \| tar xf - -C $tmp`? Though you almost definitely don't want the output of the first - if you caught it the second would have nothing to do. Still, if you mean diagnostic messages you'll want to change your command slightly like: `$({ $* ; } 2>&1)`. You might also consider switching the `$*` to `"$@"` which should be more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a pipeline like `git … | tar …` (it's a single command which contains two subcommands, not two separate commands) directly as an argument to a function, you'll need build a string containing that command, and use the `eval` builtin in the function to execute this string as a shell command.

Take care of proper quoting. For the argument, you're building a string which is a mini-shell-script using the same variables as the enclosing script. In particular, if a variable contains a file name (like `tmp` here), you need to pass the variable expansion, not the value of the variable, because a file name isn't a shell snippet, so you need `'…"$tmp"…'`, not `"…$tmp…"`. When evaluating, you need to pass the exact string to `eval`, not a string that has already undergone expansion. In particular, `$*` is pretty much always wrong; read [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

```
try () {
  result=$(eval "$1" 2>&1)
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    failure
    echo $result
    exit 1
  fi
  success
}
try 'git archive --format=tar HEAD | tar xf - -C "$tmp"'
```

An alternative approach is to stuff the compound command in a function. Again, take care of proper quoting. Use `"$@"` to evaluate the parameters of the function as a simple command (alias, function, builtin or external command with arguments).

```
try () {
  result=$(eval "$1" 2>&1)
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    failure
    echo $result
    exit 1
  fi
  success
}
archive_to_directory () {
  git archive --format=tar HEAD | tar xf - -C "$1"'
}
try archive_to_directory "$tmp"
```

The status of a pipeline is the status of its right-hand side; the status of the left-hand side is ignored. In bash (but not in sh), you can access the status of all the commands in a pipeline through the [`PIPESTATUS` variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PIPESTATUS).

```
try () {
  result=$(eval "$1" 2>&1)
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    failure
    echo $result
    exit 1
  fi
  success
}
archive_to_directory () {
  git archive --format=tar HEAD | tar xf - -C "$1"'
  [[ -n ${PIPESTATUS[*]//[0 ]/} ]]
}
try archive_to_directory "$tmp"
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add some quoting on the command line, there's no way to avoid that

```
try "git archive --format=tar HEAD | tar xf - -C $tmp"
```

Then in the function, since shell metachars (like `|`) are not special when stored in a variable, so you'll need `eval`

```
try() {
  if result=$(eval "$*" 2>&1); then
    success
  else
    failure
    echo $result
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

I have a feeling I haven't got that quite right. Hopefully someone will correct me.

Comment: Is it correct to use `$*` if you have one argument (because it is quoted in the call) to `try`? See Gilles' answer. I would use `"$1"`.

Comment: it's not incorrect. Since there's only 1 argument, joining the arguments together with space separator is the same as "$1".

Comment: You need `eval` here because you have a string with commands (`git` and `tar`). The metachar `|` is part of the string and some kind of command as well.